# JAR to EXE, stops working when moved from DIST directory (netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, compilation, exe, building

After my project is done I click F11 (build button).

Successful bild to: C:\Users***\Documents\NetBeansProjects\twitter1\dist\twitterapitest.jar

And the .jar works perfectly when its left at this location, even if I convert it to an EXE it works in this location.

What do I do to be able to move this file to lets say, desktop? Or even to my laptop?

My build includes twitter4j for twitter web API purposes, does this have something to do with it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A `jar` is not an `exe`. Check about setting classpaths.

Comment: Tried setting classpath for lib/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar in Launch4j when making an EXE, no luck there

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Netbeans also generates a `dist/lib` folder that contains the Java dependencies.  To run the JAR file, the dependencies must be in place.  So you should be able to copy your `dist/twiterapitest.jar` to a different directory, as long as you include the `dist/lib` folder.  If this does not work, please provide more error details.

Comment: Yes, that works perfectly. Problem is, is there any way I can make this work with only an EXE or JAR? Independantly from the lib map